# Grabbing a users LOCAL IP address in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way for me to set up a website that can grab a users LOCAL IP address? I have done quite a bit of research on this but it seems like any previous solutions that existed no longer work.

Comment: Here is the api link, with you can get  IP Address and other important details https://ip-api.com/

Comment: $.getJSON('http://ip-api.com/json', function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});

Comment: What do you mean by "local" IP address?

Comment: Please post links to the previous solutions you found, and tell us how they no longer work when you tried to use them.

Comment: I need the actual LAN IP Address, not the public facing IP address @Bergi

Comment: You cannot, and should not, access these - unless your server is in the same LAN.

Comment: The server will be on the same LAN. I am trying track which of our computers click on a link @Bergi

Comment: In that case, just send a request to your server and use the sender IP address there.

Comment: i think that you can try `nodejs` `dns` built-in module